# Efficient Way of shuffling 3 bit values inside an AVX2/ymm register

Tags: c, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I have an interesting problem that can't think of an efficient way of solving with vectorized code.

I have a `ymm` register with 8 32-bit integers, where each integer is made up of:

- Lower 24 bits are `8`x`3bit` "individual" values
- Top `8` bits contain a **single** `3` bit value, "unrelated" to THIS problem, but ideally I'd keep
  that value intact without touching that `3` bit value.
  I can move that `3` bit value WITHIN the top 8 bits freely, but I'd like to keep
  somewhere in there ideally...

What I'd like to do is find a way to "transpose" the 3-bit values so that (showing the first 3 elements):

```
Legend: 
z -> 8 Top-level bits I'd like to keep in place/don't care about)
a..x -> groups of 3-bit values I'd like to transpose over the ymm register
vvvv Source vvvv
-----------------
|MSB                          LSB|MSB                          LSB|MSB                          LSB|...
|zzzzzzzz...............cccbbbaaa|zzzzzzzz...............kkkjjjiii|zzzzzzzz...............sssrrrqqq|...
|zzzzzzzz...............qqqiiiaaa|zzzzzzzz...............rrrjjjbbb|zzzzzzzz...............ssskkkccc|...
-----------------
^^^^ Dest ^^^^
```

I can perform 8x(`extract`+`pdep`+`vmovq`+`vpmovzxbd`+`vpslld`+`vpor`) operations, something along the lines of:

```cpp
// N, is a constant 0..7
__m256i src;
__m256i dest;
 _mm256_or_si256(
    dest, 
    _mm256_slli_epi32(
      _mm256_cvtepi8_epi32(
        _mm_cvtsi64_si128(
         _pdep_u64(_mm256_extract_epi32(src, N), 0x707070707070707)
        )
      ), 
      3
    )
  );
```

But that is around 6x8 instructions to perform the transpose.
I'd like to think there is something magical that I could pull off with AVX2 that could make this sort of thing much shorter/faster, but I can't come up with anything for now, if anyone has any guidance as to what I could do differently, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Some shifts to set up for some `pshufb` and bit blends should work.  Or at worst 8x shifts and then bit-blend (using the usual AND / ANDN -> OR) should work.  If you're clever about when you mask (before vs after shifting) you might not need too many separate mask constants.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the hint and gentle shove. From your experience, this should result in fewer instructions?

Comment: Yes, at worst 8 shifts and 7 blends if there isn't anything cool we can do with vpshufb.  Some of the blends can be `vpblendw` or even just `vpor` when the shifted results have zeros in compatible places.  Other blends might be able to use `vpblendvb` (2 uops), while others will need the full 3 uop (3 instruction) VPAND / VPANDN / VPOR.

Comment: If you had AVX512VBMI I'd look into 2x `vpmultishiftqb` to grab bit-ranges, then vpternlogd to bit-blend.

Comment: Oops, I misinterpreted what you were doing; I was thinking you were reversing order of fields within 32-bit elements.  But on a closer look at your diagram I found `iii` and `qqq` in the source. So nevermind, you're going to need shuffles to move bytes around the whole width of the register.  But you can definitely do stuff in parallel for multiple fields at once using `vpshufb`, maybe 2 different `vpshufb` and bit-blend.  (And of course some lane-crossing shuffles).  I expect there's something better than your scalar pdep / vpmovzx / vpor, sequence though.

Comment: `vpshufb` can move bytes around.  No field can span more than 2 bytes, so with a shuffle + shift you can get multiple fields into the right place per element with one `vpshufb`.

Comment: OK, You've given me a lot of food for thought. I'll start with a pen and paper as I'm not grand wizard of vpshufb/pshufb. Only done simple stuff with it thus far.

Comment: Lisp systems use the same technique to keep tag of the objects in the first/last 3 bits.  Just consider retagging a new object at each operation that could overwrite them -- in case this is what you want to do.

Comment: Not sure it’ll be faster than your code, but AVX2 has vector shifts like  `_mm256_sllv_epi32`, can shift 32-bit lanes by variable amount of bits / each, and it’s relatively fast. The problem is you’ll need many of them.

Comment: So you are doing a 8x8 transpose of 3bit values stored in a very compressed way. Have you considered uncompressing them (either to 4bit values, or even 8bit values), do whatever operations you need to do on them (I guess this is just one step of what you actually want to do) and only compress them at the very end?

Comment: @chtz:The thing is I do need the 3 top most bits to stay in place, ideally.
I could push everything by one more bit and then have 8x4bit values, but it would be less ideal for me, I think